# How to render different dimensioned rectangles with the same border texture and have the corners not stretch?

Tags: javascript, three.js

This is my texture.
I would like to have a bunch of differently sized rectangle, that means they can all have different aspect-ratios.

If I use one [texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq9nZ.png)

[image]

on a Plane, then the textures would get stretched, especially around the corners. (I don't care if the middle gets scratched since its just a gradient).

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TzEN.png).

[image]

If possible, I would like to have differently sized rectangles all use one texture and have the corners not stretched. Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy7vN.png).

[image]

Comment: You need to research texture mapping.

Comment: or draw it in shaders

Comment: The term for this seems to be "9-slice" or "9-slicing", in case you want to look for existing solutions.

Comment: @ChrisG, is there an example of 9-slicing in three.js.

Comment: Don't think so. You could write a javascript function that uses a canvas to create the texture on the fly in the proper size maybe?

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/74t261k8/

Answer (score 0):

I made a BufferGeometry implementation of 9-slicing.
It works by creating 9 planes with respective normal UVs.
When you stretch it, only the edges and center plane is scaled, so the corners don't get distorted.

```
const basePlaneVertices = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0];

class NineSlicePlane extends THREE.Mesh {
    constructor(material, dimensions = { width: 100, height: 100, border: 25 }, uvBorder = 0.25) {

        let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

        let vertices = [];
        let uvs = [];

        const vertexOffsetsX = [0, dimensions.border, dimensions.width - dimensions.border, dimensions.width];
        const vertexOffsetsY = [0, dimensions.border, dimensions.height - dimensions.border, dimensions.height];
        const uvOffsets = [0, uvBorder, 1 - uvBorder, 1];

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
                    vertices.push(
                        basePlaneVertices[k * 2] * (vertexOffsetsX[i + 1] - vertexOffsetsX[i]) + vertexOffsetsX[i] - dimensions.width * 0.5,
                        basePlaneVertices[k * 2 + 1] * (vertexOffsetsY[j + 1] - vertexOffsetsY[j]) + vertexOffsetsY[j] - dimensions.height * 0.5,
                        0
                    );
                    uvs.push(uvOffsets[i + basePlaneVertices[k * 2]], uvOffsets[j + basePlaneVertices[k * 2 + 1]]);
                }
            }
        }

        geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(vertices), 3));
        geometry.setAttribute('uv', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(uvs), 2));

        super(geometry, material);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).